# Windows 11 search UI looks like Windows 10 search UI - How to fix?

Tags: windows-search, windows-11

My Windows 11 search UI looks like Windows 10 search UI.
(I tried to reset explorer.exe but it did not work)

[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: Well that is how Windows 11 search UI looks like. There is no problem in your Search UI.

Comment: I think what you see is more likely your theme, not how you upgrade.  I have 2 Windows 11 machines (new and Insider) and search on both is the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How did you upgrade to Windows 11? By Windows Update, Windows Update Assistant or ISO?

If you upgraded using Windows Update Assistant, then there will be issues. You must update using the ISO image or by normal Windows Update.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer suggests that the behavior being described in the question is caused by using the update assistant which could not be farther from the truth.  However, the majority of the answer, is just a comment

Comment: Yes.  I have not seen any such behavior caused by the method of installing Windows 11 including Windows 11 Production.